# Is it good to use a eclipse and sdk bundle over manual configured eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android. to work with android sdk i got a full package combined with eclipse and android sdk named "adt-bundle-windows-" . is it good to using this bundle or should i manually configure a new eclipse classic of Helios ? Because i am having some problem with the emulation and sdk mananger. 
Basically i want to know is it better to use this bundle over manually configured eclipse?
advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle should make your life easier-  everything is configured correctly for you.  It can be done manually if you really want to, but there's no promise the plugin will work with older versions.

Comment: ok, but i just wondering does manually configured eclipse shows better performance than the bundle in any point of view ?

Comment: Not unless there's features of the other version that you need (or features of the bundled ones you can't stand).

Answer (score 0):

here is a really good tutorial for you, with it you'll learn everything you want to know, there you have everything from start till end.... hope you like it! i was using it and it's perfect,

http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A